# Discord JS: Shutdown bot via slash command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following command.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")

module.exports ={
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("shutdown")
    .setDescription("Shutdown the bot"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply("Shutting down").then(() => {
            client.destroy();
        })
    }
}
```

The command should shutdown the bot. The only thing it is doing at the moment is crashing the bot because `ReferenceError: client is not defined`.
I appreciate any help

Comment: When you execute the command, send the `client` variable along with the `interaction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
process.exit()
```

Or

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")

module.exports ={
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("shutdown")
    .setDescription("Shutdown the bot"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply("Shutting down").then(() => {
            interaction.client.destroy();
        })
    }
}
```